# how to test passing data from $.post to php file in query

Tags: php, mysql, post

I want to test passing data from $.post to php file in query

this is my $.post

```
$( "#get_route").on('click', function() {
        var imei = $('#hisdeviceimei').val();

        $.post( "vehicle_route_qry.php",{ imei:imei.replace(/,\s*$/, "") },function(data) {  

        alert(data);
        });


});
```

this is php file

```
 <?
 include 'connect_old.php';
 session_start();

 $appuser = $_SESSION['LOGIN_user'];
 $username = $_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS'] ;
 $imei   = $_REQUEST["imei"];

 echo $imei;
 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

I am not able to get return values(imei) in response . How can i get / test values ?

Comment: Btw: get rid of `$_REQUEST` and also `@`s

Comment: You have short tags enabled?

Comment: yes.....................

Comment: Is there an error or everything runs smoothly but alerts an empty value?

Comment: empty value      ...